# printf compiler optimization? can't find "%s" characters in gdb on the stack

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, gdb, printf

When my program is disassembled in gdb, I can see the address of buf be pushed onto the stack, but I don't see the format string pushed onto it. Any reason why this is? Is it a clever compiler optimization?

I've tried compiling a few different variations of printf statements to see if I could mimic the "%s" string (or address of it) not being pushed onto the stack, but I couldn't do it.

This is the program code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[128];
    if(argc < 2) return 1;

    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);

    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

compiled with gcc 4.5.2, 32 bit linux

Comment: Could it be passed through a register then?

Comment: maybe it optimized it to a sys_write system call?

Comment: Thanx for sharing - I never knew gcc would do that (substitute "puts()" for "printf()").  But apparently it can - and does :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it appears that gcc will throw away "printf ("%s\n", buff)" and substitute "puts()" in its place:

> ```
> vi tmp.c =>
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[128];
    if(argc < 2)
      return 1;

    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

> $ gcc -S -Wall -pedantic tmp.c
>   less tmp.s =>

```
        .file   "tmp.c"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx
        andl    $-16, %esp
        pushl   -4(%ecx)
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        pushl   %ecx
        subl    $148, %esp
        movl    %ecx, -140(%ebp)
        movl    -140(%ebp), %eax
        cmpl    $1, (%eax)
        jg      .L2
        movl    $1, -136(%ebp)
        jmp     .L4
.L2:
        movl    -140(%ebp), %edx
        movl    4(%edx), %eax
        addl    $4, %eax
        movl    (%eax), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
        leal    -132(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    strcpy
        leal    -132(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    puts
        movl    $0, -136(%ebp)
.L4:
        movl    -136(%ebp), %eax
        addl    $148, %esp
        popl    %ecx
        popl    %ebp
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: wow, i really wasn't thinking. thank you. for some reason i still had the idea that puts took a %s argument. maybe i need to lay off the computers for a little...

Answer (score 1):

The following answer applies to x86 64bit assembler.

Short answer: x86 does not have %s as some kind of assembler instruction, that is pure c and even java nowadays aswell.

Long answer:

- Compile your program with symbols (non stripped): `gcc -g yourprogram.c`
- Dump the assembly with intermixed c-code: `objdump -S yourProgram.o`

The following text shows how `strcpy` and `printf` is shown in assembly. I have also added how you should read the assembly:

```
strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
4005eb:       48 8b 85 60 ff ff ff    mov    -0xa0(%rbp),%rax
Move argv[0] to %rax register
4005f2:       48 83 c0 08             add    $0x8,%rax
Add 8 to %rax which means we now store argv[1]
4005f6:       48 8b 10                mov    (%rax),%rdx
Copy argv[1] to the destination register %rdx
4005f9:       48 8d 85 70 ff ff ff    lea    -0x90(%rbp),%rax
Move buf to %rax
400600:       48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
Move argv[1] to %esi which is the source register implicitly used by string funcs
400603:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
Move buf to destination register 
400606:       e8 85 fe ff ff          callq  400490 <strcpy@plt>
Call strcpy which uses %rsi and %rdi

Now we have argv[1] in buf, right!?

printf("%s\n", buf);
40060b:       48 8d 85 70 ff ff ff    lea    -0x90(%rbp),%rax
The first line loads what you have at the base pointer -0x90 to the %rax register which means that it loads the address of buf into rax as buf is on the stack.
400612:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
Just mov it to the %rdi register.
400615:       e8 86 fe ff ff          callq  4004a0 <puts@plt>
Call the puts function with buf
```